# Show that: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{\frac{\log x}{\log\log xn-\log\log n}-\log\left(n\right)}=\sqrt{x}$.

Tags: limits, wolfram-alpha

I want to show that:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{\frac{\log x}{\log\log xn-\log\log n}-\log\left(n\right)}=\sqrt{x}$$

I looked it up on **[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20e%5E%28%5Cfrac%7B%5Clog%28x%29%7D%7Blog%28log%28xn%29%29-%5Clog%28log%28n%29%29%7D-%5Clog%28n%29%29)**, and it says:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{\frac{\log x}{\log\log xn-\log\log n}-\log\left(n\right)}=1$$

I got confused because it didn't match my computation results, suggesting that:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{\frac{\log x}{\log\log xn-\log\log n}-\log\left(n\right)}=\sqrt{x}$$

However, I did try **[WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20e%5E%28%5Cfrac%7B%5Clog%281234567%29%7D%7Blog%28log%281234567n%29%29-%5Clog%28log%28n%29%29%7D-%5Clog%28n%29%29)** for some values of $x$, and it gave the right value:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{\frac{\log2}{\log\log2n-\log\log n}-\log\left(n\right)}=\sqrt{2}$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{\frac{\log7}{\log\log7n-\log\log n}-\log\left(n\right)}=\sqrt{7}$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{\frac{\log31}{\log\log31n-\log\log n}-\log\left(n\right)}=\sqrt{31}$$

What is going on here? And how can I show the limit is $\sqrt{x}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. If $x>0$ then the limit is $\sqrt{x}$.
Note that as $n\to +\infty$,
\begin{align}\log(\log(nx))&=\log\left(\log(n)\left(1+\frac{\log(x)}{\log(n)}\right)\right)\\
&=\log(\log(n))+\frac{\log(x)}{\log(n)}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\log^2(x)}{\log^2(n)}+o(1/\log^2(n)).
\end{align}
Hence 
\begin{align}\frac{\log(x)}{\log(\log(nx))-\log(\log(n))}-\log\left(n\right)
&=
\frac{\log(n)}{1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\log(x)}{\log(n)}+o(1/\log(n))}-\log\left(n\right)\\&=\log(n)\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\log(x)}{\log(n)}+o(1/\log(n))\right)-\log\left(n\right)\\
&=\log(\sqrt{x})+o(1)
\end{align}
and the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Add Assumptions->{x>0} to your Limit command to get the desired $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Thanks for that! It does in fact answer the “What is going on” part!